# Scrapy - should I be concerned with viruses?

Tags: python, security, scrapy

I am currently trying to scrape through URLs that I obtained from various user web access logs using the Scrapy framework. 
The only thing that my spider is scraping, is the information in the 'title' meta tag, and the 'keyword' meta tag for each URL. No downloads of pdf, csv, txt, etc.

Should I be concerned about the crawler downloading a virus while it crawls? If not, why?

Comment: The crawler isn't smart enough to download anything other than the HTML; and it doesn't run any javascript so you are okay.

Comment: you're downloading text, as long as you don't explicitly  execute anything or interpret it as some script there's no way for that to be compromised.

Comment: I see. Yes, the spider is fairly simple so it shouldn't execute anything. Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)